# CSS not working fine

Tags: html, css

Today I was trying to build my first static website.
The HTML and CSS code are not finished yet, but the CSS seems to have no effect.
After reading a bit about CSS and HTML I still have not found what I did wrong.

Code:

```css
  body {
    #box1 {
      background-color: white;
      border: 3px blue solid;
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="new_file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>QuizChallenge</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box1">
    WebQuiz
  </div>
```

Comment: Invalid CSS! Remove the `body {` code.

Comment: Follow [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) they have plenty of tutorials for beginners.

Comment: @ZumryMohamed thanks, I will start right now.

Comment: @schaeffer.heng However I really doubt this question will be asked again, consider to mark one of the answers below. It will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `body {'...'}` from your CSS file like this:

```css
#box1 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px blue solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  WebQuiz
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete `body{` 
It is note like html: you just have to put the element you want to change it.

```
#box1 {
    background-color: white;
    border:3px blue solid;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Have a nice day ;)